# show all product from a specific category in email template

Tags: magento-1.9

Want to create a transaction email in Magento with the following criteria:

- Shows all product from a specific category where a custom attribute is "True"
- Shows product name, custom price field and two other custom attribute fields in grid format in the email.

I looked over the transaction email documentation as well as extensions from Magento and only found information on selecting specific product ID's to display rather than a statement for all products that fit a certain criteria.

Any help to lead me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

On Magento CE 1.9

Answer (score 2):

Email templates uses standard CMS filtering so you can use block or layout directive. Check here for more information: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-cms-syntax-part2/. You can also compate new_order email template in `app/locale/en_US/email/template/sales/order_new.html`